# Partitioning Sets in Groups

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I bumped into an algorithmic problem in work. I am a little bit rusty on partitioning problems and I decided to ask here. So here is the problem:

Consider a finite set C of disjoint finite sets {s1, s2, ..., sN}. Sets sJ contains some proto-elements. The number of proto-elements in each set sI is known (or can be found) in advance. Group the sets in C into disjoint groups {g1, g2, ..., gL} so that the number of proto-elements in each group is less than or equal to a given K and the number of groups is minimal.

Explanations: The members of a gI are some sets sJ. The number of proto-elements in gI is simply the sum of the numbers of proto-elements in each sJ belonging to gI.

Example: {s1, s2, s3, s4}, s1 has 1 proto-elements, s2 has 1 proto-elements, s3 has 4 proto-elements, s4 has 2 proto-elements; k = 4

Partition 1: {g1, g2, g3}, where g1={s1, s2}, g2={s3}, g3={s4}. The total number of proto-elements in all groups is less than or equal to 4.

Partition 2: {h1, h2}, where h1={s1, s2, s4}, h2={s3} and it complies with the condition of minimal number of groups.

For my practical purposes I could live with any grouping as long as the groups has less then k proto-elements. I implemented a naïve algorithm:

```
1) Initialize the current group to an empty collection
current_group={}
2) Initialize the running count of proto-elements in current_group to 0
running_count=0
3) For each set S in C
3.1) Let count be the number of proto-elements in S
3.2) If count is 0 (S is empty), continue with the next iteration
3.3) new_running_count = running_count + count
3.4) if new_running_count < K {
         add the current set S to current_group
         running_count = new_running_count
     }
3.5) else { /* new_running_count is equal to greater to K */
         print current_group
         running_count = count
         current_group={}
         add the current set S to current_group
     }
4) After the loop ends print current_group if it is not empty
```

Obviously this algorithm does not generate the minimal number of groups. I would be very grateful if you give me any hints how to solve this. Pointers to books, articles, etc. is great, no need to write the code for me. I would search for the solution myself if the problem has a well-known name.

Regards
rambius

Comment: This is the same as [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) with K as the bin capacity, and the number of proto-elements as the item size.

Comment: It looks like the "sets" s1, s2, ..., sN are conceptually not sets at all, but just numbers. And you're trying to partition these numbers into groups so that the sum of the numbers in each group is less than or equal to K.